# React useEffect everytime when state changes

Tags: reactjs

I want to add the this.state.products array into local storage everytime, when it is updated. However, as useEffect works only outside component with state, it doesn't accept the state value.

```
const products = this.state.products;
useEffect (() => {
  localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(this.state.products));
}, []);

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };
};
```

Comment: Where is you `useState` being implemented? It doesn't appear to be inside a component..

Answer (score 1):

what you are doing is wrong, you cannot have both class components and function component at the same time, if you want to persist your data in an advance way with redux, you can use `redux-persist`, but for small cases like this, you need to have a function component like below:

```
function App(props) {

   const [products, setProducts] = useState([WHAT_EVER_PRODUCT_DATA])

   // ...some other logic you wrote


   useEffect(() => {

      localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));

   }, [products])


   // ... rest of the code


}
```

this `useEffect` would run after products are changed every single time, because it depends on `products`, if you want to run it on every state change, you can skip the `[products]` of your `useEffect` but its is not recommended way of doing that!!!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `this.state.products` outside if the component who's state you are trying to access. If you want to use `App` as a class component, then you can import a functional component that uses `useState` and update that child component when `App`'s state updates.

**App.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };
};

   render(){
      return(<div><ChildComponent products={this.state.products}/></div>
   }

}
```

**ChildComponent.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const ChildComponent = ({products})=>{

   const [myProducts, setProducts] = useState([]);

   useEffect (() => {
      localStorage.setItem("myProducts",JSON.stringify(products));
   }, []);

   return(<div>
        RENDER PRODUCTS
   </div>)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` is intended to be used in React's functional components. If you want to do this in the class component I suggest the following way:

Create a new function that updated the products:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
            redirect: false,
            name: "", 
            ean: "", 
            type: "", 
            weight: "", 
            color: "", 
            active: false,
            products: [{name: "Cabbage", ean: "00000000", type: "Vegetable", weight: "2kg", color: "Green", active: false}, 
            {name: "Banana", ean: "111111111", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.3kg", color: "Yellow", active: false}, 
            {name: "Chocolate", ean: "22222222222", type: "Candy", weight: "0.2kg", color: "Brown", active: false}, 
            {name: "Orange", ean: "3333333333", type: "Fruit", weight: "0.5kg", color: "Orange", active: false}, 
            {name: "Cucumber", ean: "4444444444", type: "Vegetable", weight: "1kg", color: "Green", active: false}, ]
    };

  // Use this function to update products 
  updateProducts(products) {
    // Save to localstorage
    // use the this.setState() to update the products
    this.setState(products);
  }
};
```